# FTSE exposure in US Exchanges

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, etf, stock-exchanges, futures

Is there a FTSE 100 index futures contract that trades on the US exchanges? Thanks

I think there is an ETF but I am looking for futures, mainly for charting purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to get direct exposure to the FTSE 100 futures on a US Exchange, not even through an ETF. However there are ETF's where you can get a similar correlation.

But if you are just using it for charting purposes you can easily chart the FTSE 100 futures even if they are not traded on a US exchange.

The symbol is Z on the LIFFE exchange

Here is more info:

[FTSE 100 INDEX FUTURE](http://www.euronext.com/trader/contractspecifications/derivative/wide/contractspecifications-2830-EN.html?euronextCode=Z-LON-FUT)

[Profile of the Z Futures Market](http://daytrading.about.com/od/marketprofiles/a/ProfileZ.htm)